# R: ABC error with 1 Ss

Tags: r

**Edit: Solved, the error dissapeared whe I updated the package.**

I'm getting an error when working with just one summary statistic. Is there any reason why this is happening? Is there a way to get around this problem?
Thanks

```
library(abc)
data(human)

target<-(stat.voight["hausa",])[,1]
sumstat<-(stat.3pops.sim)[,1]
modsel.ha <- postpr(target, models, sumstat, tol=.05, method="mnlogistic")

#Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
```

Aditional details: no other objects were loaded (to my knowledge) as the R session had just been started. When I use two summary statistics instead of just 1 postpr works fine.
Session details as per request from nograpes

```
    sessionInfo()
    R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
    Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

    locale:
     [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
     [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8   
     [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
    [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] abc_1.5       locfit_1.5-7  quantreg_4.79 SparseM_0.96  nnet_7.3-4    MASS_7.3-          21  

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] grid_2.15.1     lattice_0.20-10 tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: Can you post your `sessionInfo()`, your code worked fine for me in 2.15.1 on Windows with `abc` 1.6.

Comment: ditto, on Ubuntu 10.04 with R-devel/abc 1.6.  I'm also making a wild guess that evaluation might be getting messed up because you have some variables in your global workspace that are interfering (they shouldn't, but they might) ... can you replicate this in a clean (R --vanilla) session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be solved when I upgraded abc. Surely it was a bug of an old version of the package.